# Filter order in spring-boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

How can I specify order of my Filter in spring-boot? I need to insert my MDC filter after Spring Security filter. I tried almost everything but my filter was always first. This didn't work:

```java
@Bean
@Order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)
public UserInsertingMdcFilter userInsertingMdcFilter() {
    return new UserInsertingMdcFilter();
}
```

This didn't work too:

```java
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean userInsertingMdcFilterRegistrationBean() {
    FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    UserInsertingMdcFilter userFilter = new UserInsertingMdcFilter();
    registrationBean.setFilter(userFilter);
    registrationBean.setOrder(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    return registrationBean;
}
```

Comment: `@Order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE + 100)` will not work because `Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE = Integer.Max` and  Integer.Max + 100 = some negative number, this would mean a very high precedence

Comment: @Ralph - I also tried event `@Order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)` with no success.

Comment: What version of Spring Boot? Did you try 1.1.7?

Comment: @DaveSyer, I tried, no difference

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to define Servlet filter order of execution in Spring Boot application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22453707/how-to-define-servlet-filter-order-of-execution-in-spring-boot-application)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Guys from Spring helped again. See the following:

- [Make it easier to order a filter after Spring Security's filter #1640](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1640)
- [SEC-2730: Provide an order higher than LOWEST_PRECEDENCE for springSecurityFilterChain that's created by WebSecurityConfiguration #2955](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SEC-2730)

From the former:

> `Spring Security` doesn't set an order on the `Filter` bean that it
> creates. This means that, when Boot is creating a
> `FilterRegistrationBean` for it, it gets the default order which is
> `LOWEST_PRECEDENCE`.
>
> If you want your own `Filter` to go after `Spring Security`'s you can
> create your own registration for `Spring Security`'s filter and specify
> the order.

So the answer to my question is:

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean securityFilterChain(@Qualifier(AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer.DEFAULT_FILTER_NAME) Filter securityFilter) {
    FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean(securityFilter);
    registration.setOrder(Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1);
    registration.setName(AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer.DEFAULT_FILTER_NAME);
    return registration;
}

@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean userInsertingMdcFilterRegistrationBean() {
    FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    UserInsertingMdcFilter userFilter = new UserInsertingMdcFilter();
    registrationBean.setFilter(userFilter);
    registrationBean.setOrder(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    return registrationBean;
}
```

Comment: See also discussion in https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/677 and https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1640

Comment: Given `HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE = -2147483648` and `LOWEST_PRECEDENCE = 2147483647` I would assume lowest precedence would go last? Everything would _go before it_?

Comment: It should go last. From JavaDoc of @Order: *Lower values have higher priority. The default value is Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE, indicating lowest priority (losing to any other specified order value).*

Comment: @OrangeDog Precedence != priority

Comment: @Irxw plus one for the lowest value having highest priority!

Answer (score 35):

Here's an answer compatible with `Spring Boot` **2** / `Spring Security` **5** that will allow you to insert your filter in an arbitrary place in the filter chain.

My use case was a custom logging `javax.servlet.Filter` that I wanted to execute  before any `Spring Security` filters; however the below steps should allow you to put a filter anywhere in your existing Spring filter chain:

## Step 1: Find out the order of Spring filters in your existing setup.

Connect your favorite remote debugger to your application, and set a breakpoint in the `doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response)` method of `org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy`.

As of `Spring Security` **5.1.6**, that is line 311. In your debugger, find out the existing filters by inspecting `this.additionalFilters`. In my application, the order was something like:

```
0: WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter
1: SecurityContextPersistenceFilter
2: HeaderWriterFilter
...
```

## Step 2: Insert your filter in the desired place using Spring's WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and HttpSecurity

You likely already have a `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` with a `@Override configure(HttpSecurity http)` method. `HttpSecurity` exposes `addFilterBefore` and `addFilterAfter` methods to allow you to place your filter relative to an existing class in the chain. Your filter (instance) is the first argument of these methods, and the class of the filter you'd like to insert before or after is the second argument.

In my case, I wanted my custom logging filter to be first in the chain (my code snippet is Kotlin, I'll leave the Java implementation to you):

```kotlin
override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
    http
        .addFilterBefore(MyCustomLoggingFilter(), WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter::class.java)
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(
        ...
        )
}
```

## Step 3: Profit!

Use the debugging method described in Step 1 above to verify that your filter is where you intended in the filter chain.

Hope this helps someone else out there.

Comment: Thanks you. This was helpful to me in debugging.

Comment: In my case, there was no spring-security, so I debugged the order in `ApplicationFilterChain` class.

Answer (score 26):

This was fixed in Spring Boot 1.2. The security chain now defaults to order `0`.

It can also be set via properties:

```
security.filter-order=0 # Security filter chain order.
```

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1640

Comment: In Spring Boot 1.3.x it is `SecurityProperties.DEFAULT_FILTER_ORDER` and is `FilterRegistrationBean.REQUEST_WRAPPER_FILTER_MAX_ORDER - 100` or simply `-100`.

Comment: In Spring Boot 2.1.x => `spring.security.filter.order=-100`

Answer (score 5):

Note that the Spring Security filter chain is **not** all there is when it comes to filters. In fact, there is a complete (non-security) filter chain at work, with one of the filters being an instance of `DelegatingFilterProxy` which (nomen est omen) delegates to another filter called `FilterChainProxy` which manages its own sublist of filters, all geared towards security related topics. This pattern has the advantage that all security filters are in one place and ordered correctly with respect to each other. This however doesn't help you at all if you need a filter to be executed either *before* or *after* **all** security filters. While it is true that you can configure this using the `HttpSecurity` object by selecting either the first or last filter in that list, it is logically weird, since chances are your filter has nothing at all to do with security. If you set a breakpoint in `DelegatingFilterProxy::doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain)` you will see the entire filter chain of the application. You can even drill into the `FilterChainProxy` to find all the spring security filters if you want to. Then you can open the relevant classes one by one to find out their configured orders. Once you know, where your filter ought to be, you can annotate it.

If for example you need to configure a logging filter and you want to log all security failures (needs to go before `FilterChainProxy`) but also want a useful tracing ID (needs to go after `LazyTracingFilter` which has a configured default order of `TraceHttpAutoConfiguration.TRACING_FILTER_ORDER = Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE + 5`) you can annotate your filter with `@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE + 6)`.

Answer (score 3):

add

> logging.level.web=debug

in your **application.properties**, you can see details of the registered filters, including their order and URL patterns when springboot onstartup.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30703700)

Answer (score 1):

in your first case ,it is a error config,and spring's docs has special reminder :

> You cannot configure the order of a Filter by annotating its bean method with @Order.

and you can find from this: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-embedded-container-servlets-filters-listeners-beans