# Security filters are overlapping

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-oauth2

When multiple filters are added to the HttpSecurity configure method, they seem to be overlapping because only one works at the time.

This is the configure method:

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .logout().and().antMatcher("/**")
            .addFilterBefore(ssoFilter(), RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .authenticationProvider(preauthAuthProvider())
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/index.html", "/home.html", "/", "/login").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated().and().csrf()
            .csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository()).and()
            .addFilterAfter(csrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);
}
```

I've tried to specify the order but the issue still persists:

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean securityFilterChain(@Qualifier(AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer.DEFAULT_FILTER_NAME) Filter securityFilter) {
    FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean(securityFilter);
    registration.setOrder(Integer.MAX_VALUE - 2);
    registration.setName(AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer.DEFAULT_FILTER_NAME);
    return registration;
}

@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean ssoFilterRegistrationBean() throws Exception {
    FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    registrationBean.setFilter(ssoFilter());
    registrationBean.setOrder(Integer.MAX_VALUE-1);
    return registrationBean;
}

@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean csrfFilterRegistrationBean() throws Exception {
    FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    registrationBean.setFilter(csrfHeaderFilter());
    registrationBean.setOrder(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    return registrationBean;
}
```

I've followed the following thread with no success.

[Filter order in spring-boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25957879/filter-order-in-spring-boot)

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1640

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/677

Any help will be appreciated!

UPDATE:

CSRF Filter definition

```
private Filter csrfHeaderFilter() {
    return new OncePerRequestFilter() {
        @Override
        protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                                        HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
                throws ServletException, IOException {
            CsrfToken csrf = (CsrfToken) request
                    .getAttribute(CsrfToken.class.getName());
            if (csrf != null) {
                Cookie cookie = WebUtils.getCookie(request, "XSRF-TOKEN");
                String token = csrf.getToken();
                if (cookie == null
                        || token != null && !token.equals(cookie.getValue())) {
                    cookie = new Cookie("XSRF-TOKEN", token);
                    cookie.setPath("/");
                    response.addCookie(cookie);
                }
            }
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    };
}
```

SSO Filter definition:

```
public class SSORequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter extends RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter {

private boolean allowPreAuthenticatedPrincipals = true;

public SSORequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter() {
    super();
    //TODO Pull this value from a properties file (application.properties, or localstrings.properties)
    //NOTE SM_USER is the default, but you can change it like this (your company may use some other header)
    //this.setPrincipalRequestHeader("SM_USER");
}


@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
                     FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}

/**
 * This is called when a request is made, the returned object identifies the
 * user and will either be {@literal null} or a String. This method will throw an exception if
 * exceptionIfHeaderMissing is set to true (default) and the required header is missing.
 *
 * @param request {@link javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest}
 */
@Override
protected Object getPreAuthenticatedPrincipal(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String userName = (String) (super.getPreAuthenticatedPrincipal(request));
    if (userName == null || userName.trim().equals("")) {
        return userName;
    }

    return userName;
}

public boolean isAllowPreAuthenticatedPrincipals() {
    return allowPreAuthenticatedPrincipals;
}
}
```

Comment: Can you add the filter code?

Comment: Just a question. Are you using OAuth2 and @EnableOauth2Sso and try to authenticate requests containing a bearer token in the authorization header? I've done this a few days before. If this is what you want to achieve i could provide you a solution

Comment: @YannicKlem oh god yes!!!! That's exactly my case, this application has the @ EnableOaut2Sso annotation and it keeps the token to send to another application as a redirect that's why I have the csrf filter :) thank that would really help!

Comment: Hope you can wait till wednessday.. i don't have access to the code right now and i want to try something before i provide this solution.

Comment: I provided my solution. Please let me know if you found another solution, yet.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are not always executing [FilterChain.doFilter](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/FilterChain.html#doFilter(javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse)) method inside both filters. Then the filter chain stops and only one of your custom filters is executed. In this simple example both filters executed:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .addFilterBefore(new Filter1(), RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .addFilterAfter(new Filter2(), CsrfFilter.class)
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
    }

    static class Filter1 extends OncePerRequestFilter {
        @Override
        protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
            System.out.println("executed filter 1");
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }

    static class Filter2 extends OncePerRequestFilter {
        @Override
        protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
            System.out.println("executed filter 2");
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Tried it, did not work :(. I'll update the question with the filters definition.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing container registration (with `FilterRegistrationBean`) and registration in a Security filter chain (with `HttpSecurity`) and also possibly with the order of the filter chains within Spring Security. If a given filter chain is selected by Spring Security all the filters in it are not even necessarily fired anyway (filters can always switch off other downstream filters).

I suggest you stop worrying about the order in your `FilterRegistrationBeans` and use them to disable the container registration (by setting their enabled flag to false). Then think about the order of your filter chains, as specified by the `@Order` on your `WebSecurityConfigurers`. And finally you can decide if the order of the filters in a given chain matters, and if it does use the `addFilter{Before,After}` methods.

Comment: Before giving it a try with the FilterRegistrationBean I was using the addFilterBefore and addFilterAfter but even when I did only the ssoFilter worked, the csrf was not even called.

Comment: Read the answer again. If your custom filters are declared as beans, then you need to disable the container registration. A filter not firing does not mean it is not registered.

Comment: I did as you said and got the csrf filter working. Thing is, and I've looking around if someone experienced this before, the preAuthProvider *for which I use the ssoFilter() for), change the principal object completely hence loosing values that were relevant to the csrfFilter which has now became the issue. Is there a way to only change the authorities list in the Principal object during the application auth process?

Comment: This is now a different question? Probably better not to continue in comments.

Answer (score 0):

A Filter which does what you want to do does already exist. Its the `OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter`.
This filter is used if you annotate your application with `@EnableResourceServer`. If you do so this will cause, that only token based authentication will work now.
You have to set the stateless flag of this filter to `false` to allow other ways of authentication, too.

What i did is to create a class `ApiTokenAccessFilter` which extends `OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter`. This filter takes a `ResourceServerTokenServices` constructor parameter and sets the stateless flag to false.

```
public class ApiTokenAccessFilter extends OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter {

  public ApiTokenAccessFilter(ResourceServerTokenServices resourceServerTokenServices) {

    super();
    setStateless(false);
    setAuthenticationManager(oauthAuthenticationManager(resourceServerTokenServices));
  }

  private AuthenticationManager oauthAuthenticationManager(ResourceServerTokenServices tokenServices) {

    OAuth2AuthenticationManager oauthAuthenticationManager = new OAuth2AuthenticationManager();

    oauthAuthenticationManager.setResourceId("oauth2-resource");
    oauthAuthenticationManager.setTokenServices(tokenServices);
    oauthAuthenticationManager.setClientDetailsService(null);

    return oauthAuthenticationManager;
  }
}
```

In my security config i used this Filter as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableOAuth2Sso
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Autowired
  private ResourceServerTokenServices tokenServices;

  @Override
  public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated()
        .and()
        .addFilterBefore(new ApiTokenAccessFilter(tokenServices), AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.class);
  }
}
```

I think this could be easier so i opened an issue on the [spring-security-oauth Github repo](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/issues/683). I'm not sure whether this solution is the way to go, but i didn't find another alternative.