# Ordering of a spring @Bean filter

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I have a filter (CorsFilter) that is configured using @Bean. This filter should run before LogoutFilter. I can do this by calling `HttpSecurity.addFilterBefore(corsFilter, LogoutFilter.class)` method in my implementation of `ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter.configure(HttpSecurity http)`

Can I achieve the effect of addFilterBefore just using annotation. Is there an @Before or something like that?

```
Spring Core 4.2.4
Spring Boot 1.3.1
Spring Security 4.0.2
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can: `org.springframework.core.annotation.Order`

[Here](http://www.ekiras.com/2015/10/spring-how-to-define-filter-order-in-filter-chain-in-spring-boot.html) is an example

Comment: Even setting  @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE) does not it make it run before LogoutFilter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25957879/filter-order-in-spring-boot