# How to ensure custom filter is executed last in Java Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a custom filter I created and added using `FilterRegistrationBean`. I know that there is an `@Order` annotation, and you can set the order when registering the filter. However, how do I set the order as last to be executed?

Would it be `@Order(0)` or `@Order(1000000)`, for example?

Comment: Maybe `@Order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)` http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/Ordered.html#LOWEST_PRECEDENCE

Comment: Take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25957879/filter-order-in-spring-boot

Comment: @RossiRobinsion is that saying that lowest precedence gets ran first? And that since spring security filter is assigned lowest precedence it will get ran last unless you register it and set an order for it? So would me setting a filter order not even matter unless I registered the security filter?

Comment: @ahrobins it is.... "The lower the number, the higher the precedence."