# Spring boot @PostMapping for login

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I need to send an email every time a user logs into an account, but since SpringBoot is used I don't have a @PostMapping method for /login. What should I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Intercept Spring Security login request before its processing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46514979/how-to-intercept-spring-security-login-request-before-its-processing)

Comment: Are you using spring security for your login ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what you wrote, I assume that you want to send email only when user performs a successful login. You could write your implementation of `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` to send an email when user logs in succesfully.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationSuccessHandler;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
        
@Component
public class MyNotifyingAuthSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {
        
  public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request,
HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException {
        
       //send email (do it asynchronously if you can)
        
       //redirect to your homepage (page where user should land after login)
    }
}
```

Sending an email sometimes takes a lot of time, so consider doing that async not to block the login operation for too long, if your business requirements allow you to do that.