# How do I add a rate limit filter before Oauth2 filters in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a spring boot application that uses OAuth2 for authentication.  We need to rate limit attempts to sign in, the endpoint is `/oauth/token`.

I have been unable to get a filter in front of this filter, but have not been able to.

I've tried registering filters before BasicAuthenticationFilter in the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.addFilterBefore(filter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
```

I've also attempted to add this filter in the normal filter chains with order of `Integer.MIN_VALUE` where the security context has an order set via `application.properties` with the property `security.filter-order=5`.

None of these have worked.

Is there a "Spring" way to add api rate limiting? If it is via filters, is there a way to get a filter to be active before the `BasicAuthenticationFilter` or other security filters?

Comment: Could you try `OncePerRequestFilter` https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/OncePerRequestFilter.html

Comment: Your order is wrong, because it is to high (2147483640). The authorization server security configuration has order 0. So your configuration is not used. Instead of creating an additional configuration, you could change the authorization server security configuration.

Comment: Using servlet filter should also work, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25957879/filter-order-in-spring-boot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new @Component class that implements Filter and give it an @Order of HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE. Sample below:

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class PreSecurityFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain filterChain) {

        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;

        if (RATE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED) {
            // Return suitable response message
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
        } else {            
                // Only valid requests is allowed through the filter
                fc.doFilter(request, response);            
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: We ended up using the `@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)` and it is working.