# Adding filter to servletcontext using ContextStartedEvent in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlet-filters, spring-filter

I want to add a `servletFilter` after the `Applicationcontext` has been initiailized. The reason is that the filter is dependent on userdetailsService bean, which in turn is `autowired` to other dependent beans. Issue is when I build the application I can see the `onApplicationEvent` getting called but when i try to run the application(from browser) the filter is not getting called.

How do I achieve adding the filter to servlet context.

The same filters if i add it `onStartup(ApplicationContext ctx)` method of class implementing `webApplicationInitializer`, application is throwing unstatisfied dependencies error because the beans have not been initialized yet.

```
@Component
public class AppContextStartedListener implements ApplicationListener<ContextStartedEvent> {

@Autowired
private MyAppFilter myAppFilter;

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextStartedEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Context started"); // this never happens
        ServletContext = event.getServletContext // demo code to fetch Servlet 
                         Context
        FilterRegistere.Dynamic appFilter = ServletContext.addFilter("",myAppFilter)
appFilter.setInitParameter("init","initit")

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare your filter as a Bean in a Configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {

  @Bean
  public MyAppFilter myAppFilter() {
     return new MyAppFilter();
  }
}
```

This way, your filter will take place only when the app context is initialized.

Comment: actually i have multiple filter and i need to maintain the orders too. Also i need the init parameters set to filter

Comment: add @Order Spring annotation which will maintain the order for you or you can do it this way : see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25957879/filter-order-in-spring-boot