# How to add the custom Spring filter before existing Filter chain?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, servlet-filters

I have a WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter implementation class which already has two spring security filters

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().
            exceptionHandling().and().sessionManagement().maximumSessions(1);

    httpSecurity.addFilterAfter(customAuthenticationFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
    httpSecurity.addFilterAfter(customAuthorizationFilter, CustomAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
```

Now I want to add a new custom filter called **customEntryFilter** before **customAuthorizationFilter** i.e in between existing Spring filter chain without modifying the existing **WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter** implementation class.
How to do this in Spring security?

***Expected Filter order***

```
customAuthenticationFilter
customEntryFilter
customAuthorizationFilter
```

I tried with creating a **customEntryFilter** by extending the **OncePerRequestFilter** but the filter was executed at last in the filter chain

```
@Component
public class CustomEntryFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("Going via " + CustomEntryFilter.class.getName());
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

How to make this filter execute at the beginning without changing the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapterConfiguration class?
Kindly help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filter order in spring-boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25957879/filter-order-in-spring-boot)

Comment: @kasptom **@Order** helps to add the filter before or after the Whole Spring security chain. But my uses is I want to add the filter in between existing Spring security chain without modifying the old **WebSecurityConfigurerAdapterConfiguration** implementation clss.

Answer (score 0):

### Short answer to your question:

```kotlin
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@ConfigurationPropertiesScan
class CommonConfig {
    @Autowired
    lateinit var chains: List<SecurityFilterChain>

    @Autowired
    lateinit var myCustomFilter: MyCustomFilter

    @PostConstruct
    fun post() {
        chains.forEach {
            for (i in it.filters.indices){
                if (it.filters[i] is LogoutFilter) {
                    it.filters.add(i + 1, myCustomFilter)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### More details below:

Let's say we have the following chain:

```kotlin
@Bean
@Throws(Exception::class)
fun filterChain(http: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain {
    http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/first", "/second")
        .authenticated()
        .anyRequest()
        .permitAll()
        .and()
        .httpBasic()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(auditAuthenticationEntryPoint)
        .and()
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and().formLogin().disable()
        .csrf().disable()
        .cors().configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource())
    return http.build()
}
```

And we want to add the following filter to this chain between some specific filters:

```kotlin
@Component
class MyCustomFilter : OncePerRequestFilter() {
    override fun doFilterInternal(
        request: HttpServletRequest,
        response: HttpServletResponse,
        filterChain: FilterChain
    ) {
        //some work: adding headers, working with authentication or something else
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response)
    }
}
```

Here are a few ways to add our filter to the chain:

##### 1) adding the @Order annotation to the filter:

```kotlin
@Component
@Order(5)
class MyCustomFilter : OncePerRequestFilter()
```

*Note that:*

- If you do not specify an order in the annotation, then the default order is: `Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE` - your filter will be the last one in the chain.
- If you are working with Authentication in your filter (through authentication providers) then `Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE` and `Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE`
  not suitable for your case because:

  - in case `Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE` filter`SecurityContextPersistenceFilter` which will be executed after your
    filter will clear the SecurityContext even if your filter added an Authentication object to the SecurityContext
  - in the case of `Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE` your filter will not be called at all: AnonymousAuthenticationFilter will set the Authentication object to
    Anonymous and you will receive a 401 or 403 response before the chain calls your filter
  - In this case, you need to get the chain and determine the specific order of your filter
    via the `FilterChainProxy` and the `doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response)` method, getting `this.additionalFilters`. For example, `5`.
    But this is not the best way to determine the order

##### 2) The standard (and best) way is through setting up the filter chain itself:

```kotlin
    @Bean
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    fun filterChain(http: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            ...
            .addFilterBefore(MyCustomFulter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter::class.java)
            ...
        return http.build()
    }
```

#### 3) Injecting a filter into a chain in @PostConstruct

In my case, .addFilterBefore() was not possible due to the fact that
the filter was added from the starter. My starter needs to add a filter
to each chain after the LogoutFilter. Since there can be multiple chains in
a context, I add a filter to each one. Thus, when adding my starter to the application
, the filter is added to the required place without any additional configuration:

```kotlin
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@ConfigurationPropertiesScan
class CommonConfig {
    @Autowired
    lateinit var chains: List<SecurityFilterChain>

    @Autowired
    lateinit var myCustomFilter: MyCustomFilter

    @PostConstruct
    fun post() {
        chains.forEach {
            for (i in it.filters.indices){
                if (it.filters[i] is LogoutFilter) {
                    it.filters.add(i + 1, myCustomFilter)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```