# @Value variable is null in customFilter implementing Filter

Tags: spring-boot, filter, properties, configuration, servlet-filters

my custom filter is not taking value from .properties/.yml file
Note: property file is located at src/main/resources folder

```
@Slf4j
public class CustomFilter implements Filter {

    @Value("${xyz.domainName:http://localhost:8080/x1}")
    private String DOMAIN_NAME;

    private static final String REDIRECT_URL_ENDPOINT = "/v1/xyz/abc/";

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
        String url = request.getRequestURL().toString();
        String id = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);

        if (url.startsWith(DOMAIN_NAME)) {
            ServletContext context = request.getServletContext();
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = context.getRequestDispatcher(REDIRECT_URL_ENDPOINT + id);
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);
        }
        else
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

}
```

Edit (Added WebSecurityConfigClass): My WebSecurityConfig class looks like:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.addFilterBefore(new CustomFilter(), ApiKeyAuthFilter.class);

    }
}
```

Comment: Don't you have any application.properties  or application.yml file?
If yes post you yml file aslo

Comment: it should take at least default value no?
xyz:
  domainName: "http://localhost:8080/x1/" this is added in yml file

Comment: I think the way you assigned @Value in not appropiate. That's why I am asking you to post your application.yml file

Comment: It was not an issue related to the .yml/.properties file, @Alex's suggested solution worked perfectly with a little modification mentioned in the below solution comment thread.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code, you filter is not managed by the Spring Context, therefore Spring-related functionalities like @Value do not work. So, let Spring take care of your filter.

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class CustomFilter implements Filter {

@Value("${xyz.domainName:http://localhost:8080/x1}")
private String DOMAIN_NAME;

private static final String REDIRECT_URL_ENDPOINT = "/v1/xyz/abc/";

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
    String url = request.getRequestURL().toString();
    String id = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);

    if (url.startsWith(DOMAIN_NAME)) {
        ServletContext context = request.getServletContext();
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = context.getRequestDispatcher(REDIRECT_URL_ENDPOINT + id);
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }
    else
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
}

@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean registerFilter() {
    FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    registration.setFilter(this);
    registration.addUrlPatterns("/*");
    return registration;
}

}
```

If you want to register the filter before a Spring security filter you can do this:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private Customfilter customfilter;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.addFilterBefore(customfilter, ApiKeyAuthFilter.class);

    }
}
```

Comment: I tried both solutions but it's not working for me.

Comment: Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44114108/15203875. The two solutions from my answer did work for me in the past.

Comment: ``` @Bean
 public FilterRegistrationBean securityFilterChainRegistration() {
  DelegatingFilterProxy delegatingFilterProxy = new DelegatingFilterProxy();
  delegatingFilterProxy.setTargetBeanName(AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer.DEFAULT_FILTER_NAME);
  FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean(delegatingFilterProxy);
  registrationBean.setName(AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer.DEFAULT_FILTER_NAME);
  registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/*");
  return registrationBean;
 }
```
I have added this in my application class.

Comment: and added @Component(AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer.DEFAULT_FILTER_NAME) on my filter class but still getting null for that @Value variable

Comment: I updated my original answer. Please try the solution.

Comment: Thanks, Alex for your effort, but this is the exact solution I have been trying for 2 days but it is not working

Comment: protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  http.addFilterBefore(new ApiKeyAuthFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
  http.addFilterBefore(new CustomFilter(), ApiKeyAuthFilter.class);
 }
Is this thing causing the issue?, because I have added my filter in this manner in WebSecurityConfig class.

Comment: I think so.  In your implementation http.addFilterBefore(new CustomFilter(), ApiKeyAuthFilter.class); you write new CustomFilter() which creates a new object so the @Value is not working there because the new object is not managed by Spring.

Comment: I gave you an example of using the filter with Spring security in the original post.

Comment: Thanks @Alex the edited solution worked for me after doing a little modification.
1. Instead of implementing `Filter`, I extended my class with `OncePerRequestFilter`  because my CustomFilter was being called twice for a single request may be because of Autowiring it in WebSecurityConfig class.
2. I have not written the `registerBean` method for external bean registration, @Component did its job perfectly.
And yes it worked as I wanted.
Great Thanks again for helping me out with this headache :)