# Spring Security Filters list as shown in DefaultSecurityFilterChain are different from Spring document

Tags: spring, security, filter

I ran my instructor's code and put a break point at `DefaultSecurityFilterChain`'s constructor. I want to know the order of filters in the chain. I notice those filters include:

```
0 = WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter
1 = SecurityContextPersistenceFilter
2 = HeaderWriterFilter
3 = CsrfFilter
4 =  CustomerRequestParameterAuthenticationFilter (My instructor adds it)
5 =  LogoutFilter ( My instructor adds it)
6 = UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter
7 = RequestCacheAwareFilter
8 = SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
9 = AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
10 = SessionManagementFilter
11 = ExceptionTranslationFilter
12 = FilterSecurityInterceptor
```

However, in `Spring Security` **5.1.1.Release**, the filter ordering is different from what I have. The document lists:

```
0 = ChannelProcessingFilter
1 = SecurityContextPersistenceFilter
2 = ConcurrentSessionFilter
3 = UsernamePaswordAuthenticationFilter, CasAuthenticationFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter
4 = SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
5 = JaasApiIntegrationFilter
6 = RememberMeAuthenticationFilter
7 = AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
8 = ExceptionTranslationFilter
9 = FilterSecurityInterceptor
```

Reference:

- [10.1.3 Filter Ordering](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.1.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#filter-ordering)

Any idea why the filter chain in my execution is different from the document description?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try this examples?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22453707/how-to-define-servlet-filter-order-of-execution-in-spring-boot-application    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25957879/filter-order-in-spring-boot